# Linear transformation with fraction

Tags: complex-analysis

Good evening everyone! I have to solve the following exercise:
Find the transformation T that sends $2$ into $-i$, $1-i$ into $0$, and $-3$ into $1 + i$.

I applied the following formula:

$\frac{w-w1}{w-w3}*\frac{w2-w3}{w2-w1} = \frac{z-z1}{z-z3}*\frac{z2-z3}{z2-z1}$

where $z1=2, z2=1-i, z3=-3 , w1=-i, w2=0, w3= 1+i$

I did the math twice and found it:

$T(z)=\frac{(5-5i)z+10i}{(-1-2i)z+14i+2}$
The problem is that if I do the test, the only result that comes out is $T(1-i)=0$

Comment: You are using w1 = -1 instead of w1 = -i

Comment: no sorry I had written wrong

Comment: I find $\frac{(-6-8i)z+(14+2i)}{(-3+i)z+20}$

Comment: Can I upload a photo of my calculations?